# Computer does not power off after shutting down

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, shutdown

I have dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 pro.
On Windows 10, the PC goes through the usual shutting down process then the monitor turns off, but the HDD and all the fans stay powered on.
It's very similar on Ubuntu except the monitor stays on.

I've had the problem for about a year now. It originally soon, if not immediately after I installed Ubuntu through the single boot, format the hard-drive process (single boot). Windows 10 was installed after Ubuntu, but the problem persisted. I now have W10 installed first and Ubuntu second.

Not sure if this is relevant, but this is an error I get when Ubuntu boots:
[wait hw ready failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQADn.jpg)
Ubuntu displays this indefinitely when I try to shutdown: [reboot: Power down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RRbT.png)

Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-H55M-S2V

There doesn't seem to be a relevant solution for me on the internet. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try **blacklist mei_me** in blacklist.conf to disable reported boot error. But I guess this will not fix your issue.

Seems to be an ACPI problem. Update BIOS! Try some kernel boot options "acpi=off", "acpi=on" and "acpi=force" if system is then able to power off.

Use **grep -i acpi /var/log/boot.log** after boot for status.

Comment: Thanks. Blacklist mei_me removed the error. Changing the ACPI settings didn't seem to change anything. I have tried to update the BIOS in the past. It didn't work for some reason. I'll try again.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same issue with Windows 10 and a Ubuntu 19.04 live disk (with an ASUS motherboard).

The solution for me was to replace the onboard battery (CR2032).

The motherboard is 8 years, so it's not surprising that the battery would be low.
It might also be that it caused the BIOS settings to be reset.
Anyway, it's powering off correclty now, both when shutting down and using sleep mode.